# AdMob 2016. Google Play Service

Tags: android, android-studio, admob

В хелпе гугла сказано что AdMob отныне - часть google play service, и ничего скачивать не надо. Якобы всё в Android Studio есть. Более конкретно - всё на английском. Подскажите пожалуйста, как настроить баннеры и межстраничники? Есть где нибудь внятное руководство по AdMob 2016? А то  ютуб пестрит инструкциями, но все они начинаються с "скачайте jar с оффсайта", т.е. неактуальны.

Comment: ну замените скачайте `jar` на `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:XXXX` версию актуальную там `8.4.0` например, дальше не особо поменялось.  https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start вот офф сайт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё проще! Заходим в file->Project Structure->ads-> включаем Ads(ставим галочку), оно добавляет нужное в Gradle и перекомпилируется. А далее уже добавляем стройки в Activity и всё остальное.

!ВАЖНО! Версия Android Studio должна быть последней! На моей версии 1.5 оно выдавало ошибку, ссылаясь то на версию Gradle то на какие то стили. Обновив до версии 2.1 AS, оно сказало что у меня Gradle 2.8 а нужен 2.1. Но в итоге все успешно запустились.